# I need help starting Apache server with PHP on Android with Termux

Tags: php, android, apache, localhost, termux

**Hi everyone!**
*It's my first question here XD...*

I'm trying to start a web server on my LAN, but there are some problems.
Can't set Default Charset to UTF-8 on my site or enable .htaccess for setting it.
Tried adding `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8` to the end of apache's httpd.conf file, without success,my phone is rooted, this is not so important for the question itself.

*Bellow are the codes that I run from scratch:*

- `apt update && yes | apt upgrade && yes | pkg install autoconf automake bison bzip2 clang cmake coreutils diffutils flex gawk git grep gzip libtool make patch perl sed silversearcher-ag tar apache2 php php-apache`
- `ln -s /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/etc/ ~/etc`
- `touch ~/etc/apache2/extra/php-module.conf`

*Then the changes made to httpd.conf:*

- `LoadModule mpm_prefork_module libexec/apache2/mod_mpm_prefork.so` without `#` at start
- `LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so` without `#` at start
- New lines added
  `LoadModule php_module /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/libexec/apache2/libphp.so`
  `AddHandler cgi-script .cgi`
  `AddHandler php-script .php`
- At end = `Include etc/apache2/extra/php-module.conf`

**Is something else missing?**
*My site has problems with accents, invalid characters appear, so I need to change the charset!*